# Назначить компьютеру имя в командной строке (Cisco Packet Tracer)

Tags: cisco, cisco-packet-tracer

во время создания сети необходимой топологии столкнулся с вопросом описаным в заголовке. В интернете искал, но кроме того, что можно переименовать саму сеть и все ничего подходящего не нашел. Перед этим с помощью command prompt, используя **ipconfig**, задал им адреса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вобщем оказалось, что это неправильно поставленное задание. Сделать это кроме как на вкладке config в ручную, в CPT нельзя.